# The information is processed 'separately' at 5 'different' planes

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence

Is this sentence redundant?

> The information is processed **separately** at 5 **different** planes.

Can *separately* be used with *different* without adding any redundancy?

Comment: The sentence is borderline meaningless.

Comment: Not without knowing what you mean by "different planes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context, but it certainly doesn't need to be redundant in general.

Using different terminology (because what's in the question isn't entirely clear), contrast the following sentences:

1. The work is handled **separately** at 5 **different** office locations.

   - Five different and independent sets of work are conducted. The employees in the different office locations have no contact with each other, and they *separately* submit their work to a shared manager.
2. The work is handled **jointly** at 5 **different** office locations.

   - A single set of work is conducted. The employees in the different office locations collaborate on the work, and they *jointly* submit their combined work to a shared manager.

So:

> "The work is handled at 5 different office locations."
>   "Oh, is the work handled **separately** or **jointly**?"

Although the terminology is different here, the general construction of the sentence and its meaning is likely the same.